# 2 wire to 3 wire system for ZWave

Tags: relay, wiring, home-automation, electrical

I’m looking at installing a zwave system in the UK. The relays I want use require a 3 wire system. They say most of the uk is wired via a 2 wire system

This is the product

http://www.vesternet.com/z-wave-fibaro-relay-insert-2-1-5-kw-3085

My question,  can a 3 wire system be created from a 2 wire system?

I’m confused by this and welcome any explanation.

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnjxKk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. (a) Your UK ceiling light wiring. (b) What the device requires. (c) A possible solution.*

Two options:

- Get a neutral down to your switchbox. This is likely to be very difficult.
- Mount the Z-wave device in the ceiling near the lamp where you can pick up the neutral.

With option (c) you could short out SW3 and put a blank cover-plate on the wallbox but it leaves you with no way to properly isolate the lamp when changing a bulb other than switching off the circuit-breaker.

> My question, can a 3 wire system be created from a 2 wire system?

No.